# Error taglib in my jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have a project where i use Maven and Struts 1.3.10.

***My dependencies in my Pom.xml:***

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-tiles</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

I have errors in my JSP,

***Example of JSP:***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html-el" prefix="html" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic-el" prefix="logic" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean-el" prefix="beanEl" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://fckeditor.net/tags-fckeditor" prefix="fck" %>
<%@taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/" prefix="customTag" %>

<!-- Importation du CSS pour le widget Dialog -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<html:rewrite page="/css/yui/container.css" />"></link>
<!-- Importation du CSS pour le widget Calendar -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<html:rewrite page="/css/yui/calendar.css" />"></link>
```

The problem is i have full of errors compared my taglib

> Can not find the tag library descriptor for
>   "http://struts.apache.org/tags-html-el"
>
> Can not find the tag library descriptor for
>   "http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic-el"

etc, etc...

why it's wrong

Comment: Don't you think you are nesting double quotes?

Comment: You don't seem to have the EL tag libraries in your POM.

Comment: @SMA Shouldn't matter; the JSP will process the JSP `<html:rewrite>` tags before the client sees the HTML `<link>` tags.

Comment: @DaveNewton there is not in the `struts-taglib` or `jstl`..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the EL tags are generally unnecessary in today's server environments they're bundled separately. (They were before, too, but for different reasons.)

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts-el/1.3.10

```
➜  struts  jar tf struts-el-1.3.10.jar | grep tld
META-INF/tld/
META-INF/tld/struts-bean-el.tld
META-INF/tld/struts-html-el.tld
META-INF/tld/struts-logic-el.tld
META-INF/tld/struts-tiles-el.tld
```